# How to compare two separate dates using the Boost library?

Tags: c++, boost

```
gregorian::date date1 = 2014-12-18;
gregorian::date date2 = 2014-12-19;
gregorian::date currentDate;

if(date1 < date2)
{
    date1 = currentDate;
}
else
{
    date2 = currentDate;
}
```

Functionality similar to this is ideal for my problem and I was wondering if it's at all possible to compare dates or if there is an existing function to do so?

Comment: ＋１ for creativity in initializers. Tempted to come with a UDL that allows to write dates in this way: `2014-12-19_d`. Entirely feasible in c++11

Comment: I was wrong: operator precedence require to write **[`2014-(12-18_d)`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ce6359978a03ac3)**. That's sad. Now we can't have better than **[`2014_y-12-18`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89e94373088e923f)** I think.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you need to properly construct the dates, but otherwise the comparison is no problem whatsoever.

Note that you need `day_clock` to get the `currentDate` (otherwise instead you get `not-a-datetime`)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfbbe210e583c390)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_date.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;

int main() {
    gregorian::date date1(2014, 12, 18);
    gregorian::date date2(2014, 12, 19);

    std::cout << date1 << ", " << date2 << "\n";
    (date1 < date2 ? date1 : date2) = gregorian::day_clock::local_day();
    std::cout << date1 << ", " << date2 << "\n";
}
```

This replaces the lowest value with the current date, printing

```
2014-Dec-18, 2014-Dec-19
2014-Dec-19, 2014-Dec-19
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation about gregorian dates says that all comparisons operators are available. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_operators

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want this:

```
gregorian::date date1 = 1984; // 2014-12-18 = 2014 - 12 - 18 = 1984
gregorian::date date2 = 1983; // 2014-12-19 = 2014 - 12 - 19 = 1983
```

Try looking at:

```
date(greg_year, greg_month, greg_day)
```

or

```
date from_string(std::string)
```